# What do a & b stand for in .Aggregate( (a,b) => statement w/ a&b)

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to think of the best way to word this to get to my exact question without having someone have to explain what Aggregate does because I know that's been covered in depth here and elsewhere on the internet. When calling Aggregate() and using a linq statement like

```
(a,b) => a+b
```

What is a and what is b? I know a is the current element, but what is b? I've seen examples where it seemed like b was simply one element ahead of a and other examples where it seemed like a was the result of the previous function and other examples where it seemed like b was the result of the previous function.

I've looked through the examples on the actual C# documentation pages here
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548744.aspx
and here
http://www.dotnetperls.com/aggregate

But I just need some clarification of the difference between the two arguments in the linq expression. If I'm missing some fundamental Linq knowledge that answers this, feel free to put me in my place.

Comment: It depends which signature you're calling.

Comment: a and b are the parameters to the lambda delegate being passed into Aggregate. Their types are (unless you get a compiler error) inferred by the C# compiler, will vary depending on context and thespecific extensionmethod being invoked, and can be determined by hovering over them in the RHS of the lambda.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`a` isn't the current element - `b` is. The first time that the lambda expression is invoked, `a` will be equal to the `seed` argument you gave to `Aggregate`. Each subsequent time it will be equal to the result of the previous invocation of the lambda expression.

Comment: All answers were right and helped me understand what was going on, but I felt like this one was the most concise.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at the example at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548651.aspx

```
        string sentence = "the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";

        // Split the string into individual words. 
        string[] words = sentence.Split(' ');

        // Prepend each word to the beginning of the  
        // new sentence to reverse the word order. 
        string reversed = words.Aggregate((workingSentence, next) =>
                                              next + " " + workingSentence);

        Console.WriteLine(reversed);

        // This code produces the following output: 
        // 
        // dog lazy the over jumps fox brown quick the
```

In this example, the anonymous function passed to `Aggregate` is `(workingSentence, next) => next + " " + workingSentence`.  `a` would be `workingSentence` which contains the result of the aggregation up to the current element, and `b` would be the current element being added to the aggregation.  In the first call to the anonymous function, `workingSentence = ""` and `next = "the"`.  In the next call, `workingSentence = "the"` and `next = "quick"`.

Answer (score 4):

If you're calling the overload that takes a Func matching that description, you're most likely using this version:

[Enumerable.Aggregate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548651.aspx)

That means that `a` would be your accumulator and `b` would be the next element to work with.

```
someEnumerable.Aggregate((a,b) => a & b);
```

If you were to expand that out to a regular loop, it might look something like:

```
Sometype a = null;

foreach(var b in someEnumerable)
{
    if(a == null)
    {
        a = b;
    }
    else
    {
        a = a & b;
    }
}
```

Would perform a bitwise-and and store the result back into the accumulator.